# CSS3 animation reverse direction

Tags: css, animation, direction

Let me paste my code first

```css
p{
 width: 100px;
 margin:auto;
 text-align:center;
 }
 p:hover{
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAAFCAYAAAAALqP0AAAALUlEQVRIie3TsREAIBDDsMD+Oz8LcGmhkCZw4zXJBLjarwPgZwaBwiBQGASKA4VqAgiKrgQoAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -100% 6px;
  animation-name: in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  /*animation-direction: reverse;*/
 }
 
 @keyframes in {
    0% { background-position: -100% 6px; }
    100% { background-position: 100% 6px; }
}
```

```html
<p>TESTING</p>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ykmy7k8z/)

I want the background to animate from left to right but failed to acquire that. I tried `animation-direction: reverse;` without any luck.

Can you guys please guide me to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just reverse the keyframes?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work for me.
I've added demo, please check if you got a sec.

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to reverse after you remove the mouse? Or do want the initial animation to play in the other direction?

Comment: @IFightCode I Think You Have to Check My Ans :) its work properly !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply `background-position: 200% 6px;` for the keyframe `100%`.

```css
p{
  width: 100px;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
 }
 p:hover{
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAAFCAYAAAAALqP0AAAALUlEQVRIie3TsREAIBDDsMD+Oz8LcGmhkCZw4zXJBLjarwPgZwaBwiBQGASKA4VqAgiKrgQoAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: -100% 1px;
  animation-name: in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-direction: reverse;
 }
 
 @keyframes in {
    0% { background-position: 100% 6px; }
    100% { background-position: 200% 6px; }
        }
```

```html
<p>TESTING</p>
```

Here is the [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/LzQydY)

Comment: its not work properly !! and as well its again come on the top !!

Comment: its still not work properly , i think you have to check ans again :)

Comment: Not still not bro , please update it, other i upadted my self

Comment: I can't get you what you are telling, Here It's working fine. checkout the https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/LzQydY

Comment: i updated your ans, you can check you ans , you get the idea

Comment: I have a one doubt, at 0% we have applied 100%, then why we need to apply -100% as an background-position.

Comment: If we apply -100%, then our background will slides from left to right

Comment: check your codepen its actual line is moving to right side !! just check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156121/discussion-between-rishikesh-kumar-and-satheesh-kumar).

Answer (score 3):

**I Think Its Work Fine**

```
   p:hover{
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAAFCAYAAAAALqP0AAAALUlEQVRIie3TsREAIBDDsMD+Oz8LcGmhkCZw4zXJBLjarwPgZwaBwiBQGASKA4VqAgiKrgQoAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: -100% 1px;
        animation-name: in;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-direction: reverse;
    }

    @keyframes in {
        0% { background-position: 100% 6px; }
        100% { background-position: 200% 6px; }
}
```

---

```css
p{
 width: 100px;
 margin:auto;
 text-align:center;
 }
 p:hover{
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAAFCAYAAAAALqP0AAAALUlEQVRIie3TsREAIBDDsMD+Oz8LcGmhkCZw4zXJBLjarwPgZwaBwiBQGASKA4VqAgiKrgQoAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -100% 1px;
  animation-name: in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-direction: reverse;
 }
 
 @keyframes in {
    0% { background-position: 100% 6px; }
    100% { background-position: 200% 6px; }
}
```

```html
<p>TESTING</p>
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine, however, I wanted to keep the image to be there instead of animating out.

Comment: @IFightCode :) if Its Fine Then Please Can Accept the Ans :)

Comment: mage to be there instead of animating out @ So You face any problem ?

Comment: @IFightCode Can You Please Marked as Correct in My ans :)